# Same Google Maps V2 API KEY with different package names?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

In the documentation for creating a key for using google maps v2 in android, i can see this step:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=es

```
Obtain a Google Maps API key

If your application is registered with the Google Maps Android API v2 service, then you can request an API key. It's possible to register more than one key per project.

Navigate to your project in the Google APIs Console.
In the Services page, verify that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
In the left navigation bar, click API Access.
In the resulting page, click Create New Android Key....
In the resulting dialog, enter the SHA-1 fingerprint, then a semicolon, then your application's package name. For example:
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75;com.example.android.mapexample
```

I can read that you must write the package name of the app.... so... what happens if i need to use this key in a lot of apps with different package names? It is absolutely neccesary for me to do it because of my framework. In the past google maps v1 it was possible to do it!

Thanks

Comment: have u creat map key or map api is enable

Comment: what???? i think you dont understand my question

Comment: Create multiple keys then.

Comment: follow this post, he can help you - [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296226/using-one-google-maps-api-key-for-different-android-applications

Comment: thanks itzhar but that does not solve my problem, because you need to add a line for each package name, i need to use the same allways